# Reverse animating menu and making it mobile only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code which animates a menu on my site, but I only want it to take affect on screens smaller than 800 px. and I wanted it to animate hiding from the bottom of the screen

in head

```
<script>
var didScroll;

$(window).scroll(function(event) { didScroll = true; });
setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
  $('#BN-nav').removeClass('BN-nav-show').addClass('BN-nav-hide');
  didScroll = false;
}else{
  $('#BN-nav').removeClass('BN-nav-hide').addClass('BN-nav-show');
}
}, 400);
</script>
```

html

```
<nav id="BN-nav" class="row BN-nav-show ">  ...  </nav>
```

css

```
  #B-navN {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%; min-height: 75px;
  background-color: #fff;
  }

  #s-nav.BN-nav-hide { bottom: -75px; }
```

Comment: What part doesn't do what you think it's supposed to?

Comment: Well I can't seem to get it to work only on < 800px screens, but th art that doesn;t seem to work right is animating down, It works ok to animate up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trying to use this code instead.

```js
var lastPos=0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
 if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
   $('#nav-BN').addClass('BN-nav-hide').removeClass('BN-nav-show');
 
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
   $('#nav-BN').addClass('BN-nav-show').removeClass('BN-nav-hide');
    }, 1000));
 }
});
```

```css
#nav-BN {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%; min-height: 75px;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom:-30px;
 transition:0.2s ease all;
  }

  #nav-BN.BN-nav-hide { bottom: -75px; }
  #nav-BN.BN-nav-show { bottom: 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-BN" class="row BN-nav-show ">  NAV GOES HERE  </nav>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

There have been quite a few issues with your original code, the biggest one probably being trying to add a class to the nav with the "nav-BN" ID, and you tried using `$('BN-nav')` which looks for a `<BN-nav></BN-nav>` (You should have used `$('#nav-BN').

Learn more about the jQuery selectors [here](http://Here).

**Edit:** Changed the code according to reappear when the user stops scrolling.

Comment: Ahh good catch, but your snippet removes the functionality that my code does (menu disappears when scroll down and doesn't come back)

Comment: The nav re-appears when your user gets to the top of the page. Do you need it to come back even if you scroll up just a little?

Comment: exactly, up or down it want it to go away then come back when the user stops scrolling

Comment: Please see this codepen here: http://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/bZRkOR
I wrote it so the scrol reappears after 1 second (I think it might be a bit annoying if it appears exactly when the user stops scrolling) but you can change that as you wish from 1000 (milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Window width can be obtained from the **Window Object**'s [innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth).

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth
```

Usable as

```
if (windowWidth < 800) {
  //code
}
```

Usually requires an event handler for window resize event the keep variable updated.

```
window.onresize(function() {
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth; // references previously declared variable
})
```

Also highly recommending using [Request Animation Frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of Scroll event. See [this short tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/) for more info.